# Last button in my scroll view cannot register touch

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a scrollView with buttons. Which buttons on display can be touched but in button(Scrolled) not

My code:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let randomXPos = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.width)))
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(randomXPos, 1370)
self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = true
```

screen shots of iphone 6

[image]

[image]

Comment: If possible please share screen shot of that screen...

Comment: Yeah, screenshot images or at least more code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your views using view debugger and ensure that your button is inside the scrollview. Sometimes if you adjust the content size of scroll view the button could be gone out of the scroll view.

Comment: Thank it is help. Problem was with view debugger of view controller